# Get and Transform Database Connection Security

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have been experimenting with the Get and Transform features. I have hooked up to several of my company’s databases and have created a report to show departmental performance in almost real time. The report provides loads of insight that was never available before and has been a massive success; higher management now basically live in this spreadsheet.

The problem I have is that I have now been asked to create reports for lower level employees but there are some security concerns that I need to overcome. The databases that I have hooked up to contain very commercially sensitive information that we don’t want any employee to have full access to. The data I am presenting to the user in the sheet itself is fine. The problem is that for the user to be able to refresh the data in the sheet it is still connected to the databases. If someone who knew what they were doing got access to the sheet they could basically download the full contents of these databases. Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

I’ve Googled around loads but come up with nothing. I have tried refreshing the data and then breaking the connections so that I can periodically send them a static version. The problem is that the slicers then stop working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? Are you running Windows on a domain controller?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about creating and using a separate "child" database that pulls the information you require automatically from your "parent" database?

Then just hook into your child database, and the lower level employee could potentially look that the child database, but only the source data would be available.

That source data could potentially be summarized in the database automatically if too sensitive.